# How do produce a filtered version of a log file using a string identifier?

Tags: bash, logging, csh

My Java application logs everything with the user id of the currently logged in user prepended to the log message.

I usually do a

`less myapp-log.log`

to read the log, but many users might be using the application at the same time, while I am often interested to see what a particular user did, when debugging.

Is there some way to produce a filtered version of the log such that I see only the activity of a particular user id?

This log is on a UNIX box that I access through PuTTY.

Comment: `tail -f log | grep "user"` ?

Comment: @123: That will work only if the `user`'s name are logged too right?

Comment: @Inian Yes, `logs everything with the user id of the currently logged in user prepended to the log message.`

Comment: @123: Seems valid now! missed it somehow! Should be the best answer!

Comment: @123 this works great! you can post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.